# Rest Api - large json

Tags: mysql, json, rest, large-data

I'm using spring boot to make my rest services and mysql as db.

I want to transfer large amount of data about 100.000 objects through the rest endpoint,but I can't find best way to do it.

For now I take all datas in db table about 100.000 rows transfer them into objects and then return as json response but this take so long the amount of json is about 10mb.

Which is the best way to do those kind of things "transfering large amount of datas through rest api" I know how to do it with paginations,but I want a better solution(if exists)

Thanks !

Comment: It sound very much like you want the impossible. And without knowing exactly what your API is for, and the kind of data you're talking about, it becomes difficult to answer your question.

Comment: what kind of information do u need exactly
let's say I have Person model with those fields
Id,FirstName,lastName,Age,Location
Also have db table with those columns with 100.000 rows

I return as json those 100.000 person objects

Comment: Well, rest API's are intended to give out reasonable small amount of json data, so the system stays responsive. The obvious solution would be, what you call: 'paginations'. Another solution is compression, which is possible. Most browsers accept compressed content, and most servers can serve it, sometimes even by default. It won't hurt to check that compression is enabled. json text compresses very well.